# VBA: DateDiff Hour Rounded off

Tags: ms-access, datetime, vba

I have the following sub in Access 2003 to return the hours elapsed bewteen two datetime fields.

```
Function DateDifferenceHour(dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date) As String
'Outputs Hours from two dates

Dim age_hour As Double

age_hour = DateDiff("h", dateStart, dateEnd)

DateDifferenceHour = age_hour

End Function
```

If I have the following: `DateDifferenceHour("07/23/2005","07/23/2005 7:30:00 PM")`.
It correctly returns **19** hours, but in reality, the time elapsed is **19 hours and 30 minutes**.

How can I modify it so it can round off to **20** hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: 
My original suggestion was "*Compute the difference in minutes, divide by 60, and round the quotient to zero decimal places*".  However, @Jean-François Corbett showed me the limitation of that approach.

```
? DateDifferenceHour("07/23/2005 7:00:59 PM","07/23/2005 7:30:00 PM")
1
```

IOW my first attempt rounded a duration of 29 minutes and 1 second up to 1 hour, which is no good.  So instead I suggest using the difference in seconds and dividing by 3600.

```
Function DateDifferenceHour2(dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date) As String
    'Outputs Hours from two dates
    DateDifferenceHour2 = _
        Format(DateDiff("s", dateStart, dateEnd) / 3600, "0")
End Function

? DateDifferenceHour2("07/23/2005 7:00:59 PM","07/23/2005 7:30:00 PM")
0
```

There is still the issue of which rounding approach you want.

I chose Format() thinking you would want 2.5 hours rounded up to 3.

The VBA Round() function uses round-to-even, so Round(2.5, 0) would give you 2.

We don't know which you want; you can tell us.  Also, dateStart and dateEnd imply dateStart will not be greater than dateEnd.  However, if it can be, consider how you want a negative duration "rounded" to the nearest hour.  Here are some examples copied from the Immediate Window.

```
? Round(-2.5, 0)
-2 
? Round(-1.5, 0)
-2 
? Format(-2.5, "0")
-3
? Format(-1.5, "0")
-2
```

Comment: Though this will round any difference in seconds in the same unexpected way that @Rick's original function rounds off differences in minutes. Maybe minutes are "small engouh" to accept this funny rounding behaviour? I don't know.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett I don't see why seconds matter for what Rick wants.

Comment: Example of input values that will round 29 minutes 01 second *up* to 1 hour: `DateDifferenceHour("07/23/2005 7:00:59 PM","07/23/2005 7:30:00 PM")`. Note that your `DateDifferenceHour2` reduces but does not eliminate the problem; the exact same issue will apply to fractions of a second as it did to fractions of a minute in your `DateDifferenceHour`, and to fractions of an hour in the OP's original function. I see no reason to assume *a priori* that this doesn't matter, but maybe the OP can live with this level of imprecision for his application. I don't know.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  Thank you, that was just what I needed.  I revised my answer.  I will appreciate seeing any shortcomings you identify so clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This works, without any unexpected rounding (aside from the precision of the `Date` type itself).

```
Function DateDifferenceHour(dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date) As String

    ' Rounds .5's to nearest even integer.
    'DateDifferenceHour = CStr( Round( _
    '    CDbl(dateEnd - dateStart) * 24 ) )

    ' Rounds .5's up. 
    DateDifferenceHour = Format( _
        CDbl(dateEnd - dateStart) * 24, "0" )

End Function
```

I put two rounding options so that it rounds to whole numbers; pick your favourite. It's way better programming practice to round explicitly and transparently than having `DateDiff` implicitly apply its unusual rounding.

Comment: You are aware, I assume, that the VBA Round() function uses banker's rounding and rounds negative numbers UP (instead of as absolute values, which is what you need in the case of, for example, credit memos).

Comment: @Rick If the time difference is 20.5 hours, do you want the return value as 20 or 21?  This function will return 20 with `DateDifferenceHour2("07/23/2005","07/23/2005 8:30:00 PM")` ... after you fix the assignment `DateDifferenceHour = `

Comment: @Rick: the previous comments appropriately draw attention to VBA's rounding algorithm: `Round` (and `CInt`) will round .5's to the nearest  *even* integer. (Everything else is rounded to the nearest integer, as expected.) There are workarounds if this behaviour is not desirable to you.

Comment: Thanks. If it is 20.5 I want it to round off to 21.

Comment: Just curious why you use CDbl().  To make it explicit for the reader?

Comment: Hmm, readability, I guess; to emphasize that I am using `dateEnd - dateStart` as a number (of days) and not really a "date". VBA being weakly typed, I generally try to follow the [Reddick VBA Coding Conventions](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbacc.asp#TypeConversion) and strive to avoid any implicit type conversions. Some may find this is overdoing it, but I generally like to err on the side of "explicitness".

Comment: VBA is not weakly typed, though it can be used with weak typing. Nobody I know who is an Access programmer with any experience writes any VBA code without OPTION EXPLICIT and using the strongest data types available. Like every language, VBA doesn't support all possible data types, so sometimes you have to compromise, but that doesn't make VBA "weakly typed."

Comment: Sorry, [strong/weak hybrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) typed. Regardless, I find it good and clean practice to avoid any implicit type conversions.

Comment: I don't think that you can call it a hybrid, as you can run it either in weak mode (without OPTION EXPLICIT) or strong mode (with it). It's either strong typing or no typing (well, everything typed as a variant). And even without OPTION EXPLICIT, you can still strongly type your variables just by declaring them appropriately. It's just that the compiler doesn't enforce things for you.

Comment: As to implicit type conversion, that's really a matter of programmer practice. I try to avoid it, too, though it's taken me years to understand the issues involved. But it's not really a matter for the language. Lots of languages do implicit type conversions and that doesn't make them inadequate.